# how to convert core query of sql in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5.2 framework. I want to find the all events that happens in next seven days. Here i have successfully find the core query but i want to convert with laravel query Can anyone help me

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `allocations` WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ;
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Allocation::where('date', '>', Carbon::now())
          ->where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->addWeek())
          ->get();
```

#### update

I'm not sure if this will also work but please try;

```
Allocation::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addWeek()])->get();
```

Comment: i think this will return me current week result but i want result for next 7 days

Comment: This is a good answer if you want the web server date timestamps. However, if you want your SQL server timestamps, you need to use raw statements

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM `allocations` WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
```

A little more complicated:

```
DB::table('allocations')->whereRaw("`date` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)")->get();
```

If you have an Eloquent model set up, then replace `DB::table()->` with your model name:

```
Allocations::whereRaw("`date` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)")->get();
```

Comment: should i used another where with whereRaw

Comment: No, not unless you're adding more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Eloquent Models:**

```
use App\Allocation; // Assuming this is your Eloquent model
use DB; 

Allocation::whereBetween('date', [DB::raw('NOW()'), 
    DB::raw('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)']);
```

**Using DB Facade**

```
use DB; 
DB::table('allocations')->whereBetween('date', [DB::raw('NOW()'), 
    DB::raw('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)']);
```

Comment: i think where you entered data it should be date

Comment: what is data in your query

Comment: Yes you're right, it's a typo. My bad. Should be date

Comment: ok can you tell me how i use model queries suppose i have find next 7 events in model so how i can i use in our controller function...